# Why does Terry Benedict refuse to kiss Tess in the art gallery?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-eleven

Benedict refuses to kiss Tess in the art gallery, dodging her to look up at the cameras, and noting that in his hotel, someone is always watching.

We later see that the two routinely meet for dinner, and even hold hands, at one of the hotel restaurants, which is surely under surveillance.

Why would Benedict refuse her embrace in one part of his hotel but not another? Is this a mistake, or am I missing something?

Comment: I took that as a reservation that he didn't want any overly affectionate photographs/videos of him with Tess, but that's highly subjective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Because Terry Benedict is a control freak with a huge ego.**

Remember that [Tess](http://oceanscollection.wikia.com/wiki/Tess_Ocean) was the curator at the museum inside the Bellagio, which Terry Benedict owns.  I'm sure that Benedict found it inappropriate to show Tess any type of affection while at the museum.

Also, the scene in which Tess and Terry are holding hands at dinner also had Danny Ocean at the table with them.  Terry Benedict is being overly affectionate because Danny Ocean was with them.  Terry only reaches for Tess after he sees the way that Tess was looking at Danny.  Terry just wanted to rub it in Danny's face that he had Tess.

Director Stephen Soderbergh explains Terry [Benedict](http://oceans11.stagekiss.net/info_characters.php)

> Benedict is a megalomaniacal control freak and ruthlessly expedient.

If you notice Terry and Tess together at the big fight, there is no real affection being shown between the two.  Terry Benedict only shows her affection when it benefits his motives.

[image: Boxing match]